# Vue How to replace variables in braces with components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So this is my html code:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component ref="my-component"></my-component>
</div>
```

js:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>This is a component!</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

I want an implementation like that:

```
<div id="app">
  {{my-component}}
</div>
```

Then it looks like

`<div id="app" >
    <div>This is a component!</div>
  </div>`

Can this be done?

Comment: [Vue supports what you're trying to do (the concept, not the syntax) via slots.](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but if it's about using components dynamically, then you can use the `v-is` attribute, where the value is the variable holding the components: `<div v-is="myComponentVariable"></div>`.

Comment: @matpb Actually, I just want use {{aaa}} to replace <aaa></aaa>

Comment: In that case, I doubt you will be able to achieve such a behavior.

Comment: @matpb so I 'm looking for your help.

Comment: VueJS uses a specific syntax to activate specific functionalities. ie.: the double curly braces `{{}}` are used for interpolation in html templates: during rendering time, Vue will parse your template and replace the content of `{{}}` for the value of its variable. Sadly, the value of these variables to be interpolated cannot be components. What you seem to want to achieve is much closer to dynamic components as I stated in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes I want to achieve much closer to dynamic component, I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want dynamic component: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <component v-bind:is="compName"></component>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '<div>This is a component!</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    compName: 'my-component'
  }
});
```

Comment: can I use {{compName}} to replace <component v-bind:is="compName"></component>?

Comment: no, the reason is, `compName` here is merely a string. so if you use `{{compName}}`, Vue will think you want to output a string `my-component`. That is often what we want. But in your case, The value of `compName` ( my-component ) is really the name of a component. And you want Vue to replace it with a component of that name, rather than outputting a string. So you need a way to tell Vue to do this, and `<component v-bind:is` is the way.